# Python on linux: Can't contact LDAP server

Tags: python, active-directory, ldap

I'm trying to extract some information from Active Directory using a python script:

```
SERVER='LDAP://my.domain.com'  
ldapobject=ldap.initialize(SERVER)  
ldapobject.protocol_version = ldap.VERSION3  
ldapobject.set_option(ldap.OPT_REFERRALS, 0)  
dn = 'my_dn'  
ldapobject.simple_bind_s(dn, PASSWORD)
```

Here I receive the error "Can't contact LDAP server".
This worked for me, but now I receive that error without making any modification. Also the server is untouched.
I searched for a solution but nothing resolved my problem.

Do you have any idea about this?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you ping the server? Can you open a raw connection on the LDAP port with `nc`?

Comment: The server is available, I have an application which connects to AD with success.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem is solved if I'm using:
    SERVER='LDAP://server_name.my.domain.com'
but I want that the server_name to be automatically found in the domain.